Understanding the behavior of an emitter follower power supply
The Art of Electronics has the following exercise:

Use a [single BJT transistor emitter] follower with the base driven from a voltage divider to provide a stiff source of +5V from an available regulated +15V supply.  Load current (max) = 25 mA.  Choose resistors so that the output voltage doesn't drop more than 5% under full load.

My circuit, and its design rationale, are below.  Why is it not operating properly?
Note: Solutions for this exercise are available.  This question concerns this circuit and whats wrong with it.

Assuming β = 100, the max current through the base is 250 uA (with the remaining current from the collector).  At 250 uA, a drop of 250 mV (5%) happens at 1 KΩ, which is the maximum resistance for R1.  Then R2 needs to be 575Ω to produce a base voltage of 5.4V, which will drop to about 5V at the emitter.
The maximum load is 200 Ω (= 5V/25 mA), and so this load should see 4.75V and 25mA.  However, here's what I get on Circuit Lab:

Almost no current (why?!).  And close to zero voltage at the base.  Why is my circuit behaving like this?


Almost no current (why?!)

The voltmeter acts like a high valued resistor. You should place the voltmeter in parallel with the load, not in series with it. The same advice applies to the voltmeter you placed in series with the base of the transistor. It is blocking most of the base current.
